# Using bind variables in Solr

Tags: database, oracle, solr

I am trying to load a huge amount of data from a Oracle database to Solr, and I see in the oracle console that Solr is not using any kind of "bind variables" in a query like:

```
select field1, field2, field3 from table where id = myId
```

Where myId is the result of a iteration. Oracle is processing querys as they had no relation between them. Are there any way to force Solr to use bind variables in solr? Thanks !!

Comment: what do you mean by bind variables? and why do you need them? is goal to index lot of data from oracle db by solr? or also something else?

Comment: On every query I do , Oracle has to go through the process of parsing the statement, working out the various execution paths and coming up with an optimal access plan before it can be executed. Bind variables are «substituion» variables that are used in place of literals and that have the effect of sending exactly the same SQL to Oracle every time the query is executed. That reduce the latch, the CPU activity and the use of the shared memory pool in Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try to set CURSOR_SHARING=FORCE for session or system.

Comment: Thanks WaldiMen, I will try your solution. Besides I will probe with a dataimport based on pl/sql to index without any restriction.